# Why does a DPM protection group configured for Sync work for some databases in simple recovery model but not others?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, recovery, sql-server-2022, dpm

I'm using System Center Data Protection Manager 10.22.197.0 to back up SQL Server 2022 CU 10 on Windows Server 2022. DPM agent is also 10.22.197.0 on these SQL servers.

The SQL Server instance was added to DPM protection (meaning that each database should be automatically added). Some of the databases on this SQL Server are in Simple recovery model, others in Full. The protection group is set to do periodic Synchronization (every 15 minutes) as well as Express Full (1/day).

I realize that Synchronization should not work for databases in Simple recovery model, but in reality, for 3 of the 4 databases in Simple recovery mode, DPM just doesn't try to do Sync jobs for them; while for the 4th database it does try the Sync and fails with the normal error for that scenario ("Execution of SQL command failed for SQL Server 2022 database on with reason: BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally. The statement BACKUP LOG is not allowed while the recovery model is SIMPLE...").

Any ideas why DPM is treating these databases differently? The only difference I've identified in the databases themselves is that the "working" ones are at compatibility level 150 and the "failing" one is at compatibility level 160.